# Where to put custom JQ functions?

Tags: module, shared-libraries, jq

I found a good set of definitions I would like to use in jq(https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq). The version I have to use don't have them built in. The page mentions that use these definition for the new functions.

I would like to know where to put these definitions so my local jq can access them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Modules section of the manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Modules):

> [...]
>
> The default search path is the search path given to the -L command-line option, else ["~/.jq", "$ORIGIN/../lib/jq", "$ORIGIN/../lib"]
>
> [...]
>
> If “$HOME/.jq” is a file, it is sourced into the main program.

`$ORIGIN` appears to refer to the directory containing the `jq` binary itself.

Comment: new URL: https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#modules